# Need help setting up Docker for my webserver

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, moodle, traefik

Right now using NGNIX with to host multi domain on a droplet but as we are bearly hitting our peaks we would liek to use this droplet to run more applications so we want to use Docker containers for the same.

Hence would like to run my websites (atleast 5 of them) in docker along with Moodle LMS or anyother LMS. Now would like a reverse DNS to sit at the listening end so it can handle the traffic and SSL and route to whichever docker continer it needs to.

Now as I'am new to docker and do not have much expertise on such thing would like to get feedback and suggestions on the same so I can start testing them on my local machine before deploying them to our prod.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The ask is I need to move by NGINX setup which is on bare metal to a docker setup and also introduce docker version of Moodle or other LMS and have a reverse proxy (like trafik) to handle all the routing with SSL.